# Inserting system timestamp into a timestamp field in hive table

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, create-table

I m using Hive 0.8.0 version. I wanted to insert the system  timestamp into a timestamp field while loading data into a hive table.
In Detail:
I have a file with 2 fields like below:

```
id name
1  John
2  Merry
3  Sam
```

Now i wanted to load this file on hive table along with the extra column "***created_date***". So i have created hive table with the extra filed like below:

```
CREATE table mytable(id int,name string, created_date timestamp) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
```

If i load the data file i used the below query:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/user/data/' INTO TABLE mytable;
```

If i run the above query the "***created_date***" field will be NULL. But i wanted that field should be inserted with the system timestamp instead of null while loading the data into hive table. Is it possible in hive. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two steps. First load data from the file into a temporary table without the timestamp. Then insert from the temp table into the actual table, and generate the timestamp with the unix_timestamp() UDF:

```
create table temptable(id int, name string)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile;

create table mytable(id int, name string, created_date timestamp)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile;

load data inpath '/user/user/data/' into table temptable;

insert into table mytable
select id, name, unix_timestamp()
from temptable;
```

Comment: Hi,I did the same thing which you have suggested but in a `created_date` field I'm not able to see the current inserted timestamp.   Here its showing  `1970-01-17 00:17:13.142`.  how can i get the inserted timestamp.

Comment: Hi, i got it!! the query is `insert into table mytable
select id, name, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) from temptable;`  Thank you so much for the help.